# Is it possible to initialize static const member object in a class in C++?

Tags: c++, static, constants, definition, class-members

Is it possible to initialize a static constant member in a class definition? Please see below for the code,

```
class foo
{
  public:
    foo(int p) : m_p(p){}
    ~foo(){}

  private:
    int m_p;
};


class bar
{
   public:
     bar(){}
     ~bar(){}

   public:
     static const foo m_foo = foo( 2 ); //is this possible?
};
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

No, until the static member is const and is of integral or enumeration type.

Long answer:

> $9.4.2/4 - "If a static data member is
>   of const integral or const enumeration
>   type, its declaration in the class
>   definition can specify a
>   constant-initializer which shall be an
>   integral constant expression (5.19).
>   In that case, the member can appear in
>   integral constant expressions. The
>   member shall still be defined in a
>   namespace scope if it is used in the
>   program and the namespace scope
>   definition shall not contain an
>   initializer."

Answer (score 3):

Not for a static data member of class type, as in your example.

9.4.2/2:

> The declaration of a static data
>   member in its class definition is not
>   a definition ... The definition for
>   a static data member shall appear in a
>   namespace scope enclosing the member’s
>   class definition.

9.4.2/4:

> If a static data member is of const
>   integral or const enumeration type,
>   its declaration in the class
>   definition can specify a
>   constant-initializer which shall be an
>   integral constant expression (5.19).
>   In that case, the member can appear in
>   integral constant expressions. The
>   member shall still be defined in a
>   name- space scope if it is used in the
>   program and the namespace scope
>   definition shall not contain an
>   initializer.